# check session in every page?

Tags: c#, .net

I am pretty new to .NET - I am making a site that has an admin section that should only be visible to logged in users.
I have created the login code and once a user is authenticated, I then assign them a session variable. 
My question is : is there a more efficient way to check the session variable rather than having the following function on each page?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      checkSession();

 }
public void checkSession()
{
    if (Session["LoggedIn"] != "true")
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
}
```

thanks kindly!

Comment: you could have the checkSession() function in a class, which in turn you can call cls.checkSession() and return a bool;

Comment: You need to stick with `Form Authentication` which uses `cookie`

Comment: Why "true"? use true instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are using a `MasterPage` you can put the checking code in the `MasterPage's Page_Load` event if not use either the `Global.asax` or a custom `HttpModule` and put the cheking code inside the the `AcquireRequestState` event handler for the first and the `PostRequestHandlerExecute` event handler for the second

**Exmaple with Global.asax**

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{ ...
    void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        // CheckSession() inlined
        if (context.Session["LoggedIn"] != "true")
        {
          context.Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
    }
  ...
}
```

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: When redirecting to default.aspx, still not logged so redirect again to default.aspx

Comment: I don't agree putting code to MasterPage. What if ContentPage(uses master) requires a validation?

Let me explain; think about some code in Profile.aspx which uses Master.site. 
When Profile.aspx is loaded, lets page need Session values. However, session haven't controlled yet. Because Master.site controls it. In this case, NullReference exception throws in Profile.aspx.

DO NOT check Session in the Master page.

Adios amigos/amigas

Answer (score 3):

You should probably consider using forms authentication:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication/using-basic-forms-authentication-in-aspnet

You can configure a page, or folder to always require authorization, so the runtime will take care of that requirement rather than you having to check manually.

Comment: Forms authentication is also a more well rounded security system and includes several advantages over simple Session checking, see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443

Answer (score 2):

Derive your pages from a custom class that derives from Page

override the Load method by adding your session check code

now all your pages have the validation

```
public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (Session["yoursession"] != "true")
   {
     //code
   }
 }



public class yourCustomPage1 : MyPage
{   
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   //you don't have to check or call any method..
 }
}

public class yourCustomPage2 : MyPage
{   
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   //you don't have to check or call any method..
 }
}
```

etc...

Comment: It would be useful to have a code sample that illustrate this.

Answer (score 2):

You could make your page a class that inherits from a base class that checks for logged in users.

Comment: I think this is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to start to understand forms authentication in ASP.Net is creating a brand new website.
Go in Visual Studio and create New Project, select Web, then ASP.NET Web Application.
Check it out in Account folder to understand the process and ASP.Net methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can create BasePage and inherit all your page from this base page , set the function in your basepage.

```
public class BasePage : Page
{
   protected void checkSession()
   {
    if (Session["LoggedIn"] != "true")
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
   }
}
```

Your Page

```
public partial class YourPage : BasePage
{
....
}
```

Another solution :

In your Http Module, create Principal(Roles) and Identity in order to set authentification and authorization functionnalities, in your http module attach theses informations to current thread.

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.isauthenticated.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
            public class BasePage : Page
            {
             protected void checkSession()
               {
                  if (Session["LoggedIn"] == null)
                   {
                           Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx/");
                    }
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1st Way : Global.asax.cs ADD

```
    void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        Page page = context.Handler as Page;

        if ((string)context.Session["LoggedIn"] != "true"
            && !(page.AppRelativeVirtualPath == "~/Default.aspx"))
            context.Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
```

2nd Way : You can have the same session management in Master page. Page Load event.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in the GLOBAL.asax.cs this will check if the session is empty and also it will not redirect if this the request is initialized from the Login page otherwise it will stuck in a loop.

```
 void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        // CheckSession() inlined
        if (Context.Request.Url.LocalPath != "/UIComponents/User/Login.aspx")
        {
            if (context.Session["Name"] == null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
            }
        }
    }
```